# NGINX For 100K+ R/S

Tags: optimization, nginx, server, webserver

I am trying to tune NGINX for INSANE amounts of traffic.

I have a huge dedicated server and my website keeps going down during times of very high traffic.

Although when I check top, I see almost no CPU usage.

How can I increase the amount of CPU that NGINX uses?

Here is my current nginx configuration

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 16;
worker_rlimit_nofile 819200;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 161920;
    # multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
# set client body size to 2M #
client_max_body_size 2M;
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 8096;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 16 cores you can increase worker_process.
Check out: https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/

However, are you sure it's crashing out due to CPU utilization and not RAM or something else (like maybe your application)? Make sure you check your error log and collect metrics because I'd be surprised (especially based on what you said) if it had to do with CPU load. I recommend something like Munin (http://munin-monitoring.org) to collect solid metrics and try to better figure out what's really going on.

Comment: If it is RAM, how can tune the RAM?

Comment: KiB Mem:  32875688 total,  1502100 used, 31373588 free,

Comment: Well that memfree doesn't tell you much you need to look specifically at what is using RAM especially during the time of high load. Is nothing being logged when it crashes?